# Swift protocol generics error(ORM implementation)

Tags: ios, swift, orm, metaprogramming

I'm trying to implement a ORM layer on top of Couchbase Lite iOS 2.0, now it did removed the CBLModel apis which make it a little bit difficult to use.

I'm using a Reflection lib and its Mappable protocol(which is renamed to ORMMappable in the following code) to simplify the mapping apis.
Here's the error message:

> let t = Self.cast_id_type(type: link, obj: value)
>
> Cannot invoke 'cast_id_type' with an argument list of type '(type: ORMMappable.Type, obj: Any?)'
>
> 1. Expected an argument list of type '(type: D.Type, obj: Any?)'

And here's the problematic code

```
typealias MappableDictionary = [String : Any]

class IDString<T:ORMMappable> : NSString{
    func load_object(){
    }
}

struct MapMeta{
    var ignores : [String] = []
    var mapping : [String:ORMMappable.Type] = [:]
}

protocol ORMMappable {
    var id : NSString {get set}
    static var _meta : MapMeta{get}
    init(dictionary: MappableDictionary) throws
}
extension ORMMappable {
    init() throws{
        try self.init(dictionary: [:] as MappableDictionary)
    }
    
    static func cast_id_type<D:ORMMappable>(type: D.Type,obj: Any?) -> IDString<D>?{
        if let o = obj as? IDString<D>{
            return o
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    init(dictionary: MappableDictionary) throws {
        self = try construct { property in
            let meta = Self._meta
            if let value = dictionary[property.key] {
                if let type = property.type as? ORMMappable.Type, let value = value as? MappableDictionary {
                    return try type.init(dictionary: value)
                }
                else if let link = meta.mapping[property.key]
                {
                    let t = Self.cast_id_type(type: link, obj: value)
                    print(link)
                    //return t
                    return nil
                }
                else {
                    return value
                }
            } else {
                return nil
                //throw Error.missingRequiredValue(key: property.key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A example of usage is

```
struct TestObject : ORMMappable{
    static var _meta: MapMeta{
        return MapMeta(ignores: [], mapping: ["link_id":TestObject2.self])
    }
    
    var id : NSString
    var name : String?
    var age : Int?
    var link_id : IDString<TestObject2>?
}
```

IDString is holder for a link to other ORMMappable compatible class, mapping maps from String(property name) to a ORMMappable compatible class, and cast_id_type does check the mapping and trying to cast from the pointer of value to the StringID object. The error itself makes me quite confused here,

```
static func cast_id_type<D:ORMMappable>(type: D.Type,obj: Any?) -> IDString<D>?
```

D should be a ORMMappable compatible class, where I give is a value of a [String:ORMMappable.Type], but it rises ORMMappable.Type is not D.Type, how does this comes from?

Also I'm looking forward if there any better ways to do ORM in swift, currently the code does working with dynamic object creation, but when comes with ORM relation, it really drove me nuts here, just looking for ways to manage it in a easier and more manageable ways, where currently it  looks like there are not much functionalities to do meta programming, a lot of other ORM libs still using objc, which is much more easier(but boilerplate) on dynamic instance creation or class inspection.

Thanks very much for the help, any hints will be real appreciated :)

Comment: You can't infer a generic type using a runtime parameter, it has to be a concrete type that is known at compile time.

Comment: hi dan, thx for the quick response, so problem roots from a runtime type cannot be inferred to generics type here?hmmmmm, so I is there anyway to cast such types with swift?

Answer (score 0):

Removed all generics solved the problem, it won't inferred in runtime environment.